# CSS Selectors (first, first-child, nth-child) Targeting Not Selecting in Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to target several td elements in jQuery using CSS Selectors.

- I need the first element (td.calsun_days) to be a part of the click event adding the "selectedWeekend" class.
- I need the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, and 5th td elements to be adding the class "notAllowed" to them upon page load.
  [image: Need]
  [image: What is happening now]
  The issues that I'm having are that the elements are not targeting correctly for the "notAllowed" class. It's selecting tuesday through saturday, and only on click. The "selectedWeekend" class is being added to friday/saturday on click (only if the "notAllowed" code is not there), but not sundays. I've tried switching the order of the code but it didn't have any impact. I've tried targeting using first-child, first, nth-child(1), and nth-child(2). Thanks in advance for any help!

### jQuery

```js
jQuery(document).ready(
  function($) {
    var element = $('#afterbig1 td.czr-focus td');
    element.click(function() {
      if ($(this).is(":nth-last-child(2)") || $(this).is(":last-child") || $(this).hasAttribute('class')) {
        $(this).toggleClass("selectedWeekend");
      }
    });
    if (element.is(":nth-child()") || element.is(":nth-child(2)") || element.is(":nth-child(3)") || element.is(":nth-child(4)")) {
      element.addClass("notAllowed");
    }
  });
```

```css
 @media only screen and (max-width : 640px) { 
    #views_tabs ,#drop_down_views
    {
        display:none;
    }

    #views_tabs_select
    {
        display:block !important;
    }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width : 968px) { 
        #cats >li
        {
            float:none;
        }
    }

    .spider_categories{
        display:inline-block;
        cursor:pointer;
    }

    .spider_categories p{
        color: #fff;
        padding: 2px 10px !important;
        margin: 2px 0 !important;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 600;
    }
 
#cats #category
{
    text-decoration:underline;
    cursor:pointer;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bigcalendar1" class="wdc_calendar" style="width:196.078431372549%;">     
      <div id="afterbig1" style="" class="wdc_calendar">
      <div style="width:100%;">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;">
          <tbody><tr>
            <td>  
              <div id="views_tabs" style=";width: 100%;">
                <div class="views" style="" onclick="showbigcalendar('bigcalendar1', 'https://johnabounceandplay.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=spiderbigcalendar_day&amp;theme_id=13&amp;calendar=12&amp;select=month,week,day,&amp;date=2017-11-23&amp;many_sp_calendar=1&amp;cat_id&amp;widget=0&amp;rand=1','1','0')"><span style="top: -3px; position: relative; color:#FFFFFF;font-size:13px">Day</span>
                </div>
                <div class="views" style="" onclick="showbigcalendar('bigcalendar1', 'https://johnabounceandplay.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=spiderbigcalendar_week&amp;theme_id=13&amp;calendar=12&amp;select=month,week,day,&amp;months=10,11,12&amp;date=2017-11-23&amp;many_sp_calendar=1&amp;cat_id&amp;widget=0&amp;rand=1','1','0')"><span style="top: -3px; position: relative; color:#FFFFFF;font-size:13px">Week</span>
                </div>
                <div class="views" style="display:none;" onclick="showbigcalendar('bigcalendar1', 'https://johnabounceandplay.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=spiderbigcalendar_list&amp;theme_id=13&amp;calendar=12&amp;select=month,week,day,&amp;date=2017-11&amp;many_sp_calendar=1&amp;cat_id&amp;widget=0&amp;rand=1','1','0')"><span style="top: -3px; position: relative; color:#FFFFFF;font-size:13px">List</span>
                </div>
                <div class="views" style="background-color:#005478 !important;top:0;" onclick="showbigcalendar('bigcalendar1', 'https://johnabounceandplay.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=spiderbigcalendar_month&amp;theme_id=13&amp;calendar=12&amp;select=month,week,day,&amp;date=2017-11&amp;many_sp_calendar=1&amp;cat_id&amp;widget=0&amp;rand=1','1','0')"><span style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:13px">Month</span>
                </div>
              </div>
    
    <div id="views_tabs_select" style="display:none">
    <div id="views_select" style="background-color:#005478 !important;color:#FFFFFF !important;font-size:13px">
    Month<div class="arrow-right show_arrow"></div>
    <div class="arrow-down"></div>
    </div>
    <ul id="drop_down_views" style="float: left;top: inherit;left: -20px;margin-top: 0px;">
    <li style="">
    <div class="views_select" onclick="showbigcalendar('bigcalendar1', 'https://johnabounceandplay.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=spiderbigcalendar_day&amp;theme_id=13&amp;calendar=12&amp;select=month,week,day,&amp;date=2017-11-23&amp;many_sp_calendar=1&amp;cat_id&amp;widget=0','1','0')">
    <span style="position:relative;top:25%;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:13px">Day</span>
    </div>
    </li>
    
    <li style=""><div class="views_select" onclick="showbigcalendar('bigcalendar1', 'https://johnabounceandplay.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=spiderbigcalendar_week&amp;theme_id=13&amp;calendar=12&amp;select=month,week,day,&amp;months=10,11,12&amp;date=2017-11-23&amp;many_sp_calendar=1&amp;cat_id&amp;widget=0','1','0')">
     <span style="position:relative;top:25%;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:13px">Week</span>
    </div>
    </li>
    
    <li style="display:none;"><div class="views_select" onclick="showbigcalendar('bigcalendar1', 'https://johnabounceandplay.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=spiderbigcalendar_list&amp;theme_id=13&amp;calendar=12&amp;select=month,week,day,&amp;date=2017-11&amp;many_sp_calendar=1&amp;cat_id&amp;widget=0','1','0')">
    <span style="position:relative;top:25%;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:13px">List</span>
    </div>
    </li>
    
    <li class="active" style=""><div class="views_select" onclick="showbigcalendar('bigcalendar1', 'https://johnabounceandplay.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=spiderbigcalendar_month&amp;theme_id=13&amp;calendar=12&amp;select=month,week,day,&amp;date=2017-11&amp;many_sp_calendar=1&amp;cat_id&amp;widget=0','1','0')">
    <span style="position:relative;top:25%;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:13px">Month</span></div></li>
    
    </ul>
    </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="general_table" style="border-spacing:0; width:100%;border:#005478 solid 0px; margin:0; padding:0;background-color:#F8F8F8 !important;">
                <tbody><tr>
                  <td width="100%" style="padding:0; margin:0;" class="czr-focus">
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-spacing:0; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0; width:100%;">
                      <tbody><tr style="height:40px; width:100%;">
                        <td class="top_table" align="center" colspan="7" style="position: relative;padding:0; margin:0; background-color:#005478;height:20px; background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 100% 100%; border: 0 !important;">
                          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="calyear_table" style="margin:0; padding:0; text-align:center; width:100%; height:90px;">
                            <tbody><tr>
                              <td width="10%">
                                <div onclick="javascript:showbigcalendar('bigcalendar1','https://johnabounceandplay.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=spiderbigcalendar_month&amp;theme_id=13&amp;calendar=12&amp;select=month,week,day,&amp;date=2016-11&amp;many_sp_calendar=1&amp;cat_id&amp;widget=0','1','0')" style="text-align:center; cursor:pointer; width:100%; background-color: rgba(1,121,156,0.4);;">
                                  <span style="font-size:18px;color:#FFF">2016</span>
                                </div>
                              </td>
                              <td class="cala_arrow" width="11%" style="text-align:right;margin:0px; padding: 0px 30px 0px 0px;">
                                <a style="text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black;color:#CCD1D2;" href="javascript:showbigcalendar('bigcalendar1','https://johnabounceandplay.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=spiderbigcalendar_month&amp;theme_id=13&amp;calendar=12&amp;select=month,week,day,&amp;date=2017-10&amp;many_sp_calendar=1&amp;cat_id&amp;widget=0','1','0')">❰
                                </a>
                              </td>
                              <td style="text-align:center; margin:0;" width="10%">
                                <input type="hidden" name="month" readonly="" value="November">
                                <span style="line-height: 30px;font-family: Segoe UI; color:#F9F2F4; font-size:25px;text-shadow: 1px 1px  black;">November 2017 </span>
                              </td>
                              <td style="margin:0; padding: 0px 0px 0px 30px;text-align:left" width="11%" class="cala_arrow">
                                <a style="text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black; color:#CCD1D2" href="javascript:showbigcalendar('bigcalendar1','https://johnabounceandplay.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=spiderbigcalendar_month&amp;theme_id=13&amp;calendar=12&amp;select=month,week,day,&amp;date=2017-12&amp;many_sp_calendar=1&amp;cat_id&amp;widget=0','1','0')">❱
                                </a>
                              </td>
                              <td width="10%" style="border: 0 !important;">
                                <div onclick="javascript:showbigcalendar('bigcalendar1','https://johnabounceandplay.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=spiderbigcalendar_month&amp;theme_id=13&amp;calendar=12&amp;select=month,week,day,&amp;date=2018-11&amp;many_sp_calendar=1&amp;cat_id&amp;widget=0','1','0')" style="text-align:center; cursor:pointer; width:100%; background-color: rgba(1,121,156,0.4);;">
                                  <span style="font-size:18px;color:#FFF">2018</span>
                                </div>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody></table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr align="center" height="30" style="background-color:#006285 !important;">
                                              <td class="weekdays" style="width:14.2857143%; color:#CCD1D2; margin:0; padding:0;background-color:#006285 !important">
                            <div class="calbottom_border" style="text-align:center; margin:0; padding:0;"><b class="week_days">Su </b></div>
                          </td>
                                            <td class="weekdays" style="width:14.2857143%; color:#CCD1D2; margin:0; padding:0">
                          <div class="calbottom_border" style="text-align:center; margin:0; padding:0;"><b class="week_days">Mo </b></div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="weekdays" style="width:14.2857143%; color:#CCD1D2; margin:0; padding:0">
                          <div class="calbottom_border" style="text-align:center; margin:0; padding:0;"><b class="week_days">Tu </b></div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="weekdays" style="width:14.2857143%; color:#CCD1D2; margin:0; padding:0">
                          <div class="calbottom_border" style="text-align:center; margin:0; padding:0;"><b class="week_days">We </b></div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="weekdays" style="width:14.2857143%; color:#CCD1D2; margin:0; padding:0">
                          <div class="calbottom_border" style="text-align:center;margin:0; padding:0;"><b class="week_days">Th </b></div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="weekdays" style="width:14.2857143%; color:#CCD1D2; margin:0; padding:0">
                          <div class="calbottom_border" style="text-align:center;margin:0; padding:0;"><b class="week_days">Fr </b></div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="weekdays" style="width:14.2857143%; color:#CCD1D2; margin:0; padding:0">
                          <div class="calbottom_border" style="text-align:center; margin:0; padding:0;"><b class="week_days">Sa </b></div>
                        </td>
                                          </tr>
                <tr id="days" height="90" style="line-height:15px;">          <td class="caltext_color_other_months" style="background-color:#F8F8F8 !important">
                          <p style="padding-right: 7px; font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI;padding-left: 5px;background: #CCD1D2  !important; width: 100%; padding-right: 6px;">29</p>
                        </td>          <td class="caltext_color_other_months" style="background-color:#F8F8F8 !important">
                          <p style="padding-right: 7px; font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI;padding-left: 5px;background: #CCD1D2  !important; width: 100%; padding-right: 6px;">30</p>
                        </td>          <td class="caltext_color_other_months" style="background-color:#F8F8F8 !important">
                          <p style="padding-right: 7px; font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI;padding-left: 5px;background: #CCD1D2  !important; width: 100%; padding-right: 6px;">31</p>
                        </td>        <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                            <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">1</p>
                          </td>        <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                            <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">2</p>
                          </td>        <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                            <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">3</p>
                          </td>        <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                            <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">4</p>
                          </td>        </tr>
                        <tr height="90" style="line-height:15px">        <td class="calsun_days" style="padding:0; margin:0;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; font-size:17px">
                            <p style="background: #CCD1D2 ; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 6px; ">5</p>
                          </td>        <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                            <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">6</p>
                          </td>        <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                            <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">7</p>
                          </td>        <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                            <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">8</p>
                          </td>        <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                            <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">9</p>
                          </td>        <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;" class="selectedWeekend">
                            <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">10</p>
                          </td>        <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;" class="selectedWeekend">
                            <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">11</p>
                          </td>        </tr>
                        <tr height="90" style="line-height:15px">        <td class="calsun_days" style="padding:0; margin:0;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; font-size:17px">
                            <p style="background: #CCD1D2 ; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 6px; ">12</p>
                          </td>        <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                            <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">13</p>
                          </td>        <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                            <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">14</p>
                          </td>        <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                            <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">15</p>
                          </td>        <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                            <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">16</p>
                          </td>        <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                            <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">17</p>
                          </td>        <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                            <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">18</p>
                          </td>        </tr>
                        <tr height="90" style="line-height:15px">        <td class="calsun_days" style="padding:0; margin:0;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; font-size:17px">
                            <p style="background: #CCD1D2 ; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 6px; ">19</p>
                          </td>        <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                            <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">20</p>
                          </td>        <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                            <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">21</p>
                          </td>        <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                            <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">22</p>
                          </td>    <td style="overflow: hidden; color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px; border: 2px solid #005478 !important; vertical-align:top;">
                            <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI;padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">23</p>
                          </td>        <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                            <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">24</p>
                          </td>        <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                            <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">25</p>
                          </td>        </tr>
                        <tr height="90" style="line-height:15px">        <td class="calsun_days" style="padding:0; margin:0;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; font-size:17px">
                            <p style="background: #CCD1D2 ; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 6px; ">26</p>
                          </td>        <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                            <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">27</p>
                          </td>        <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                            <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">28</p>
                          </td>        <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                            <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">29</p>
                          </td>        <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                            <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">30</p>
                          </td>        <td class="caltext_color_other_months" style="font-size:17px;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI;font-weight: 600;background-color:#F8F8F8 !important;"><p style="background: #CCD1D2 ;"><span style="padding: 0px 19px 0px 5px;">1</span></p></td>        <td class="caltext_color_other_months" style="font-size:17px;line-height:1.4; font-weight: 600;font-family: Segoe UI; background-color:#F8F8F8 !important;"><p style="background: #CCD1D2 ;"><span style="padding: 0px 19px 0px 5px;">2</span></p></td>            </tr>
                      </tbody></table>            <input type="text" value="1" name="day" style="display:none" class="czr-focusable">
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody></table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody></table>
<ul id="cats" style="list-style-type:none; padding: 0;">
    <li class="spider_categories"><p id="category5" style="background-color:#f26823 !important" onclick="showbigcalendar('bigcalendar1', 'https://johnabounceandplay.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=spiderbigcalendar_month&amp;theme_id=13&amp;calendar=12&amp;select=month,week,day,&amp;date=2017-11&amp;many_sp_calendar=1&amp;cat_id=5&amp;cat_ids&amp;widget=0','1','0')"> 10AM-10:30PM</p></li>
    
    
    
    <li class="spider_categories"><p id="category6" style="background-color:#fecd0b !important" onclick="showbigcalendar('bigcalendar1', 'https://johnabounceandplay.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=spiderbigcalendar_month&amp;theme_id=13&amp;calendar=12&amp;select=month,week,day,&amp;date=2017-11&amp;many_sp_calendar=1&amp;cat_id=6&amp;cat_ids&amp;widget=0','1','0')"> 10AM-5PM</p></li>
    
    
    
    <li class="spider_categories"><p id="category7" style="background-color:#99ca3d !important" onclick="showbigcalendar('bigcalendar1', 'https://johnabounceandplay.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=spiderbigcalendar_month&amp;theme_id=13&amp;calendar=12&amp;select=month,week,day,&amp;date=2017-11&amp;many_sp_calendar=1&amp;cat_id=7&amp;cat_ids&amp;widget=0','1','0')"> 7PM-10:30PM</p></li>
    
    
    <li class="spider_categories"><p id="category0" style="background-color:#005478 !important" onclick="showbigcalendar('bigcalendar1', 'https://johnabounceandplay.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=spiderbigcalendar_month&amp;theme_id=13&amp;calendar=12&amp;select=month,week,day,&amp;date=2017-11&amp;many_sp_calendar=1&amp;cat_id&amp;cat_ids&amp;widget=0','1','0')">All categories</p></li>
    </ul>  
    
    </div></div></div>
```

Comment: [`.slice()`](https://api.jquery.com/slice/): `element.slice(1, 5).addClass(...)`

Comment: It didn't work, it targeted the top row (where the month is) and didn't do it for every row. The sunday also didnt get added to the click function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Update for WordPress Table

Added **Demo 2** which is a fix for this particular table of this particular WordPress template. For a more general and sane answer see below for **Demo 1**.

**90% of the elements have inline styles.**

```
    <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; 
    border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; vertical-align:top;">

    </td> 
    <!--Do not copy this-->
```

- **Properties that stylesheets, classes, and `.css()` cannot change by normal means**

  - `color: #004B6C;`
  - `padding: 0;`
  - `margin: 0;`
  - `line-height: 15px;`
  - `vertical-align: top`

If you wish to change these properties by external stylesheet or `<style>` block, you'll need to use `!important`.

- **These properties cannot be overridden by `!important`**

  - `border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;`
  - `border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;`

The only way to change inline styles is directly accessing them using plain JavaScript.

- **Changing the `style` *attribute* by plain JavaScript**

  - **Property:** **`style`**

    - **Signature:** element.**style**.propertyName = "propertyValue"
    - **Example:** `document.querySelector('td').style.borderBottom` `=` `"3px dashed red"`
    - **Note:** One element and one property/value only
  - **Method:** **`setAttribute()`**

    - **Signature:** element.**setAttribute(** 'propertName', 'propertyValue')
    - **Example:** `document.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].setAttribute('style', 'border-bottom: 3px dashed red')`
    - **Note:** One element multiple property/value but the original will be overwritten
  - **Attribute:** **`cssText`**

    - **Signature:** element.**style.cssText** = "propertyName: propertyValue"
    - **Example:** `$('td')[0].style.cssText = 'border-bottom: 3px dashed red';`

---

On **Demo 1** Friday, Saturday, and Sunday columns have the `.selectedWeekend` class and the added feature of highlighting cells onclick. The remaining columns have the `.notAllowed`class.

**The selector for `.notAllowed`:**

```
$('tbody tr td:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+5)')
```

**Selector**: *Find `<tbody>`, then go thru each `<tr>` to find all <`td>` that reside within the second column* (`nth-child(n+2)`) *to the fifth column* (`nth-child(-n+5)`)

**The Selector for `.selectedWeekend`:**

```
$('tbody tr td').not('.notAllowed');
```

Once the `.notAllowed` columns were determined we can just use simple process of elimination by using `not()`

**Details commented in Demo**

### Demo 1 - For non-nested valid tables (most likely not on a CMS or WordPress site)

```js
$(function() {

  /* Selector: Get all <td> inside <tbody> that is on 
  || the second, third, fourth, and fifth
  */
  var NA = $('tbody tr td:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+5)');
  NA.addClass('notAllowed');

  /* Selector: Get all <td> that DO NOT have the class .notAllowed
  || Delegate the .on() method  and invoke callback highlight()
  */
  $('tbody tr td').not('.notAllowed').addClass('selectedWeekend');
  $('.selectedWeekend').on('click', highlight);

  // Toggles background and style of a cell
  function highlight(e) {
    if ($(this).css('background-color') !== 'cyan') {
      $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
    }
  }

});
```

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 3px ridge grey;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #000
}

th {
  background: goldenrod;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px
}

.selectedWeekend::before {
  content: attr(class);
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: auto
}

.notAllowed::before {
  content: attr(class);
}

.highlight {
  background-color: cyan;
  border: 2px solid blue
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title></title>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>SUNDAY</th>
        <th>MONDAY</th>
        <th>TUESDAY</th>
        <th>WEDNESDAY</th>
        <th>THURSDAY</th>
        <th>FRIDAY</th>
        <th>SATURDAY</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

### Demo 2 - If the table is on a CMS or WordPress site

```js
//[Get all <p> in the <td>]

/* Collect all <p> that are the only-child of 
|| a <td> and the <td> a decsendant of a <tr>
|| into a NodeList then convert into an array
*/
var days = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tr td p:only-child'));

//[Set all <td> and <p> inline styles]

/* Run days array through .forEach()
|| on each loop:
|||Change the inline style of each <p> of days[]
|||Change the inline style of each <td> parent of <p>
|| *Note:* See post re: inline styles
*/
days.forEach(function(day, idx, days) {
  days[idx].style.cssText = "font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI;padding-left: 5px;background: cyan; width: 98%; position:absolute;";

  days[idx].parentNode.style.cssText = "color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2;vertical-align:top;background:goldenrod;position:relative;";

});

//[Mark all .excluded cells]

/* Get all <p> that are the only child of a <td> which
|| is a 2nd, 3rd, 4th, or 5th decsendant of a <tr>
||| On each <p> find its parent <td> and add 
|| .excluded class
*/
$('tr td:nth-of-type(n+2):nth-of-type(-n+5) p:only-child').each(function(index, wDay) {
  $(this).parent('td').addClass('excluded');
});

//[Mark each header .selected or .excluded]

/* On each td.weekdays (the headers) use .map()
|| to do the following:
||| Add .normal and .selected classes to the
|| first, sixth, and seventh <td> as well as
||| adding data-day attributes to them.
||| Add .excluded class to the rest
*/ 
$('td.weekdays').map(function(col, day) {
  if (col === 0 || col === 5 || col === 6) {
    $(this).addClass('selected normal');
    switch (col) {
      case 0:
        $(this).data('day', 'SUN');
        break;
      case 5:
        $(this).data('day', 'FRI');
        break;
      case 6:
        $(this).data('day', 'SAT');
        break;
    }
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('excluded');
  }
});

//[Mark all of the remaining cells .selected.normal] 

/* Go through each <p> parent <td> that do NOT
|| have the .excluded class and add .selected and
|| .normal class to them.
||| Because this template is overtly complex and
|| bad design, this table is inside a <td> so 
|| td.czr-focus does not need those classes
*/
$(days).parents('td').not('.excluded').each(function(index, wEnd) {
  $(this).addClass('selected normal');
  $('.czr-focus').removeClass('selected normal');
});

//[Mark the cells for Sunday, Friday, and Saturday]

/* .map() out each td.selected and add
|| .SUN, .FRI, or .SAT classes according to its
|| index position within $('td.selected')
*/
$('td.selected').map(function(idx, wEnd) {
  if ((idx + 3) % 3 === 0 && idx < 18) {
    $(this).addClass('SUN');
  } else if ([4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19].includes(idx + 3)) {
    $(this).addClass('FRI');
  } else if ([5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20].includes(idx + 3)) {
    $(this).addClass('SAT');
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});

//[Highlight a cell or column]

/* Delegate a click event on all td.selected
||| When clicked toggle the classes .highlight
|| and .normal.
||| Declare DAY as this <td>'s particular
|| value of its data-day attribute
||| if this <td> has class .weekdays and 
|| .highlight, get all <td> that has the class
|| that matches data-day attribute value of
|| the clicked header (i.e. td.weekdays) and
|| add .highlight and remove .normal to all of
|| them.
||| if this is a header in default (i.e.
|| td.weekdays.selected.normal) do the reverse
*/
$('td.selected').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('highlight normal');
  var DAY = $(this).data('day');
  if ($(this).is('.weekdays.highlight')) {
    $(`.${DAY}`).addClass('highlight').removeClass('normal');
  } else if ($(this).is('.weekdays.normal')) {

    $(`.${DAY}`).removeClass('highlight').addClass('normal');
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
```

```css
/* This makes all <td> display classList */

td::after {
  content: '['attr(class)']';
  color: red;
  font-size: 7px;
}

.weekdays,
.selected {
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.highlight {
  background: lime !important;
  border-color: magenta !important;
  outline: 4px solid magenta;
}

.normal {
  background: initial;
  border-color: initial;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="general_table" style="border-spacing:0; width:100%;border:#005478 solid 0px; margin:0; padding:0;background-color:#F8F8F8">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="100%" style="padding:0; margin:0;" class="czr-focus">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-spacing:0; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0; width:100%;">
          <tbody>
            <tr style="height:40px; width:100%;">
              <td class="top_table" align="center" colspan="7" style="position: relative;padding:0; margin:0; background-color:#005478;height:20px; background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 100% 100%; border: 0 !important;">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="calyear_table" style="margin:0; padding:0; text-align:center; width:100%; height:90px;">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td width="10%">
                        <div onclick="javascript:showbigcalendar('bigcalendar1','https://johnabounceandplay.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=spiderbigcalendar_month&amp;theme_id=13&amp;calendar=12&amp;select=month,week,day,&amp;date=2016-11&amp;many_sp_calendar=1&amp;cat_id&amp;widget=0','1','0')"
                          style="text-align:center; cursor:pointer; width:100%; background-color: rgba(1,121,156,0.4);;">
                          <span style="font-size:18px;color:#FFF">2016</span>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                      <td class="cala_arrow" width="11%" style="text-align:right;margin:0px; padding: 0px 30px 0px 0px;">
                        <a style="text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black;color:#CCD1D2;" href="javascript:showbigcalendar('bigcalendar1','https://johnabounceandplay.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=spiderbigcalendar_month&amp;theme_id=13&amp;calendar=12&amp;select=month,week,day,&amp;date=2017-10&amp;many_sp_calendar=1&amp;cat_id&amp;widget=0','1','0')">❰
                                </a>
                      </td>
                      <td style="text-align:center; margin:0;" width="10%">
                        <input type="hidden" name="month" readonly="" value="November">
                        <span style="line-height: 30px;font-family: Segoe UI; color:#F9F2F4; font-size:25px;text-shadow: 1px 1px  black;">November 2017 </span>
                      </td>
                      <td style="margin:0; padding: 0px 0px 0px 30px;text-align:left" width="11%" class="cala_arrow">
                        <a style="text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black; color:#CCD1D2" href="javascript:showbigcalendar('bigcalendar1','https://johnabounceandplay.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=spiderbigcalendar_month&amp;theme_id=13&amp;calendar=12&amp;select=month,week,day,&amp;date=2017-12&amp;many_sp_calendar=1&amp;cat_id&amp;widget=0','1','0')">❱
                                </a>
                      </td>
                      <td width="10%" style="border: 0 !important;">
                        <div onclick="javascript:showbigcalendar('bigcalendar1','https://johnabounceandplay.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=spiderbigcalendar_month&amp;theme_id=13&amp;calendar=12&amp;select=month,week,day,&amp;date=2018-11&amp;many_sp_calendar=1&amp;cat_id&amp;widget=0','1','0')"
                          style="text-align:center; cursor:pointer; width:100%; background-color: rgba(1,121,156,0.4);;">
                          <span style="font-size:18px;color:#FFF">2018</span>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center" height="30" style="background-color:#006285 !important;">
              <td class="weekdays" style="width:14.2857143%; color:#CCD1D2; margin:0; padding:0;background-color:#006285 !important">
                <div class="calbottom_border" style="text-align:center; margin:0; padding:0;"><b class="week_days">Su </b></div>
              </td>
              <td class="weekdays" style="width:14.2857143%; color:#CCD1D2; margin:0; padding:0">
                <div class="calbottom_border" style="text-align:center; margin:0; padding:0;"><b class="week_days">Mo </b></div>
              </td>
              <td class="weekdays" style="width:14.2857143%; color:#CCD1D2; margin:0; padding:0">
                <div class="calbottom_border" style="text-align:center; margin:0; padding:0;"><b class="week_days">Tu </b></div>
              </td>
              <td class="weekdays" style="width:14.2857143%; color:#CCD1D2; margin:0; padding:0">
                <div class="calbottom_border" style="text-align:center; margin:0; padding:0;"><b class="week_days">We </b></div>
              </td>
              <td class="weekdays" style="width:14.2857143%; color:#CCD1D2; margin:0; padding:0">
                <div class="calbottom_border" style="text-align:center;margin:0; padding:0;"><b class="week_days">Th </b></div>
              </td>
              <td class="weekdays" style="width:14.2857143%; color:#CCD1D2; margin:0; padding:0">
                <div class="calbottom_border" style="text-align:center;margin:0; padding:0;"><b class="week_days">Fr </b></div>
              </td>
              <td class="weekdays" style="width:14.2857143%; color:#CCD1D2; margin:0; padding:0">
                <div class="calbottom_border" style="text-align:center; margin:0; padding:0;"><b class="week_days">Sa </b></div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="days" height="90" style="line-height:15px;">
              <td class="caltext_color_other_months" style="background-color:#F8F8F8 !important">
                <p style="padding-right: 7px; font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI;padding-left: 5px;background: #CCD1D2  !important; width: 100%; padding-right: 6px;">29</p>
              </td>
              <td class="caltext_color_other_months" style="background-color:#F8F8F8 !important">
                <p style="padding-right: 7px; font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI;padding-left: 5px;background: #CCD1D2  !important; width: 100%; padding-right: 6px;">30</p>
              </td>
              <td class="caltext_color_other_months" style="background-color:#F8F8F8 !important">
                <p style="padding-right: 7px; font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI;padding-left: 5px;background: #CCD1D2  !important; width: 100%; padding-right: 6px;">31</p>
              </td>
              <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">1</p>
              </td>
              <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">2</p>
              </td>
              <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">3</p>
              </td>
              <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">4</p>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="90" style="line-height:15px">
              <td class="calsun_days" style="padding:0; margin:0;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; font-size:17px">
                <p style="background: #CCD1D2 ; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 6px; ">5</p>
              </td>
              <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">6</p>
              </td>
              <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">7</p>
              </td>
              <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">8</p>
              </td>
              <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">9</p>
              </td>
              <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;" class="selectedWeekend">
                <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">10</p>
              </td>
              <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;" class="selectedWeekend">
                <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">11</p>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="90" style="line-height:15px">
              <td class="calsun_days" style="padding:0; margin:0;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; font-size:17px">
                <p style="background: #CCD1D2 ; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 6px; ">12</p>
              </td>
              <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">13</p>
              </td>
              <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">14</p>
              </td>
              <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">15</p>
              </td>
              <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">16</p>
              </td>
              <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">17</p>
              </td>
              <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">18</p>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="90" style="line-height:15px">
              <td class="calsun_days" style="padding:0; margin:0;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; font-size:17px">
                <p style="background: #CCD1D2 ; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 6px; ">19</p>
              </td>
              <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">20</p>
              </td>
              <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">21</p>
              </td>
              <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">22</p>
              </td>
              <td style="overflow: hidden; color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px; border: 2px solid #005478 !important; vertical-align:top;">
                <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI;padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">23</p>
              </td>
              <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">24</p>
              </td>
              <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">25</p>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="90" style="line-height:15px">
              <td class="calsun_days" style="padding:0; margin:0;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; font-size:17px">
                <p style="background: #CCD1D2 ; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 6px; ">26</p>
              </td>
              <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">27</p>
              </td>
              <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">28</p>
              </td>
              <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">29</p>
              </td>
              <td style=" color:#004B6C;padding:0; margin:0; line-height:15px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important; border-left: 1px solid #CCD1D2  !important;vertical-align:top;">
                <p style="font-size:17px; font-weight: 600;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI; padding-left: 5px; background: #CCD1D2 ;">30</p>
              </td>
              <td class="caltext_color_other_months" style="font-size:17px;line-height:1.4;font-family: Segoe UI;font-weight: 600;background-color:#F8F8F8 !important;">
                <p style="background: #CCD1D2 ;"><span style="padding: 0px 19px 0px 5px;">1</span></p>
              </td>
              <td class="caltext_color_other_months" style="font-size:17px;line-height:1.4; font-weight: 600;font-family: Segoe UI; background-color:#F8F8F8 !important;">
                <p style="background: #CCD1D2 ;"><span style="padding: 0px 19px 0px 5px;">2</span></p>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table> <input type="text" value="1" name="day" style="display:none" class="czr-focusable">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The jQ/JS hasn't been tested within the full code of OP (30,000 char. limit), but it functions by itself, so it should be ok when included within your real code. The cells and the columns (click the header) of Sunday, Friday, and Saturday can be highlighted when clicked.

Comment: It's a plugin on wordpress that I'm trying to manipulate, so I appreciate the help! Do you know whether I should put this JS in the footer or if I can put it in a separate file and call it from the footer?

Comment: I always have external CSS at the top in the `<head>` after `<meta>`. After that the `<style>` tag right before the `</head>` end tag. Then right before the `</body>` closing tag in descending order: `<script src="..jquery.min.js.."` then if there's Bootstrap and/or jQuery UI, then any plugins, and the last is the `<scrpit>` tag . So the script from my answer should be in the `<script>` tag, but it's fine in an external file as well as long as that file is called after jQuery, Bootstrap, and/or jQuery UI, etc.

Comment: I ran out of space in the answer so I'll mention this in comments: There's a pattern involving the tags. When you were trying those selectors you mentioned how mixed up the results were. The reason why is because there's 4 layers of nested `<table>`s so when targeting the `<td>` in the calendar, you also targeted `<td>` that were on higher up the DOM tree. There's a different pattern to every table and the calendar pattern is `td div:only-child` then you use jQ/JS to access the parent `<td>`.

Comment: Another thing to add but ran out of space is that there is a way to use jQuery to set inline styles: `$('td').attr('style', '2px dashed red; background: rgba(0,0,0,.7 ')}` . Just like it's JS counterpart `setAttribute()` it can set multiple inline styles but always overwrites the CSS line doing so.

Answer (score 1):

there you have an example of the selectors you need:

```js
$('td:first-child, td:nth-last-child(-n+2)').css('background','red');
$('td:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+5)').css('background','blue');
```

```css
td {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```